# Why is errors=remount-ro not working with hibernated Windows partitions?

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

I have a Windows 10 (ntfs) partition on my Xubuntu 14.04 laptop. I wanted to mount it automatically at startup, readonly if necessary since most of the time there is hibernation information on it. So I added the following to my /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=1AC27E82C27E6245   /media/me/DATA  ntfs    nobootwait,errors=remount-ro    0   0
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo mount -a
```

which gave me:

> The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in
>   Windows cache, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda5':
>   Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state.
>   Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast
>   restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Nothing surprising here. But since I am using the "errors=remount-ro" option in fstab, I would expect mount to have mounted the disk readonly after the error... Which it did not.

Is there a reason why "errors=remount-ro" is ignored in this case, and the disk is not mounted readonly ? Did I misunderstand this option ?

Note that I am not asking for an alternate solution; I just want to understand why this does not work as I expect it to.

Thanks !

Comment: This is the way to do it http://askubuntu.com/questions/369984/how-to-automatically-mount-hibernated-ntfs-to-read-only in case anyone wonder (and yes it does not answer the question about the "why errors=remount-ro does not work")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mounting is sent to the [ntfs-3g](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.ntfs-3g) driver and that one does not support the "errors=" option (I would call that a compatibility bug). It only supports the "ro" option. That is also why you see people using [/etc/rc.local](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369984/how-to-automatically-mount-hibernated-ntfs-to-read-only) or [xinitrc](https://superuser.com/questions/579831/mount-hibernated-windows-partition) or by adding the "remove_hiberfile" option so it does mount "rw".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Thanks to your pointers I found a bug report about this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1418560?comments=all

Comment: Oh good find. I searched bugs but did not find that one :D